# Filtering table to create another table in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot, pivot-table

I need to receive values from a table where a condition is met. For example  I have names and I need to take all values from a table where the name appears. 
For example the table consists of date, name, expenditures:

```
Date        Name    Expenditures
2019-01-28  Sara    2.45
2019-04-26  John    32.67
2019-05-07  Peter   55.88
2019-06-14  Sara    62.09
2019-07-03  Sara    12.94
2019-09-30  Peter   5.64
```

I need to receive all expenditures which has been made by Sara and the `Date` days when it was done. The result should be the following:

```
Date        Name    Expenditures
2019-01-28  Sara    2.45
2019-06-14  Sara    62.09
2019-07-03  Sara    12.94
```

I need this to appear as a table, so filtering does not do the job right here. Basically I have a large table as mentioned in the first code snippet and I need to create another table with the same structure but only filtering by the `Name`.

Comment: Pivot table is what you need.

Comment: You can use a Power Query as well and use the filters at the top to create you filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub test()

Dim allData As Range, criteriaRng As Range, i As Long

Set allData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

For i = 1 To allData.Rows.Count
    If UCase(allData(i, 2)) = "SARA" Then
    If criteriaRng Is Nothing Then
        Set criteriaRng = allData.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, allData.Columns.Count))
        Else
        Set criteriaRng = Union(criteriaRng, allData.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, allData.Columns.Count)))
    End If
    End If
Next

criteriaRng.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A11")

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Naresh, could I somehow update the code that instead of 'SARA' I would have let's say `D1` cell in which I could input either `SARA` or `JOHN` and the table would be created based on the name I've added to the selected cell?

Comment: yes... Say you want to refer to D1 and then you want a table with any name in D1 then just change the code to UCase(allData(i, 2)) = ucase(D1) Then

Comment: Thank you sir, helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. The data:
   [image: data]
2. Select any cell inside the table => Insert => Pivot Table => OK
3. Check all the fields on the right-side pane in this order: Date, Name, Expenditures.
   [image: pivot fields]
4. Right click on the month in the pivot table => Ungroup...
   [image: Ungroup date]
5. Right click on the date in the pivot table => Field Settings...
   [image: Field settings]
6. In the tab "Subtotals & Filters" choose "None".
7. In the tab "Layout & Print" choose "Show item labels in tabular form".
8. "OK".
9. Filter the table using the right-side pane. 
   [image: filtering]
10. The result:
    [image: result]