# VBA cell.value as string - Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I have a database of names, and I am trying to set it up so that I can search for a first name and then be brought to the line(s) with said first name. The code I am using right now is:

```
Option Compare Text

Sub NameFinder()
'Search for name, then produce name and birthday
Sheets("Guests").Activate

Dim s As String, r As Range, found As Integer

Set begin = Range("D2")

s = InputBox("Enter a name to search.")
Set r = Range(begin, begin.End(xlDown))

found = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r, s)
MsgBox ("There are " & found & " people with the name " & s)


For Each cell In r
    If cell.Value = s Then
    Application.Goto cell.EntireRow, tru
    End If
Next


End Sub
```

cell.Value doesn't look for strings, so it keeps giving me an error message. What can I do to stop this?

Comment: You're using an inputbox and searching for possible matches... would it be more appropriate to create an array of Unique values and use a drop-down menu?  If the name isn't found, it's not there.  You can then use the like-for-like name and goto said row.

Comment: It might be useful to know what you are trying to accomplish exactly. What do you expect to do once you are on the row of the found name?

Comment: Seems like a perfect instance to use `Range.Find`. Well, seems like you are recreating this functionality?

Comment: you may refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60378055/filtering-table-to-create-another-table-in-excel/60380873?noredirect=1#comment106839678_60380873

Comment: Seems like you can just filter for your name. If you need to modify the range you can iterate over `xlVisibleCells`. What do you want to do with the rows once you find them? Just display them?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad It is a database of everyone that has come to an event in the past and their information. I am using it so that I can just ask for their names in the future

Answer (score 1):

Just filter your range for the name

---

```
Option Compare Text

Sub NameFinder()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Guests")
Dim s As String, lr As Long
Dim Found As Range

lr = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
s = InputBox("Enter a name to search")

Set Found = ws.Range("D1:D" & lr).Find(s)

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    'Filter to name
    ws.Range("D1:D" & lr).AutoFilter 1, s
Else
    MsgBox "Name not found"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why `AutoFilter` - you have a range that you can go to directly, wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: BC I ONLY NEED 30 POINTS @BigBen

Comment: @BigBen jk haha. It looks like there is an expectation that a name may appear more than once which complicates the `Range.Find` slightly. This seems more straight forward **IF** there is an expectation that the target value is not distinct

Comment: Good catch on the plural line(s)!

Comment: Welcome to 5 digits :-)